# Why does this circuit provide the data needed to plot an I-V graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, batteries

[image]

So this circuit is used  to collect data to plot an I-V curve of a semiconductor diode. Is the variable resistor on that side of the circuit as to not effect the voltage? If someone could give me a run down on why this circuit is needed to collect the data for an I-V curve that'd be great.

I'm just not confident in knowing why the components are where they are?

Comment: Maybe you should first expend some thinking on your own to solve this homework problem and then explain where you are running into problems. This is not a homework help site!

Comment: This isn't homework, I just wanted to understand the circuit in full depth

Comment: Great a homework tag... this isn't homework. Just cause the question isn't as abstract and as complex as most doesn't mean it's homework!

Comment: Hi JudgeArmada. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your circuit, the procedure of the experiment is that you measure the voltage drops across the diode for different known values of current to study the I-V characteristics.

The diode is forward biased by connecting the positive of the battery to the p-side of the diode and the negative of the battery to the n-side. So you will be obtaining the I-V characteristics of the diode in the forward biased condition.

To study the I-V characteristics, you need the values of voltage drops across the diode for different forward currents. That's why you connect a variable resistor (a rheostat can also do the job). By adjusting the variable resistor, you can control the current flowing through the circuit (and of course through the diode).

To measure what current flows through the circuit (or diode), you connect an ammeter series with the diode and the battery. Now you can fix a particular value of current, say  $10 mA$ by adjusting the variable resistor. Then to measure the voltage developed across the diode, you connect a voltmeter across the diode. This is the experimental setup.

Now, to do the experiment, set the current (indicated in the ammeter) to a known value by adjusting the variable resistor. Then observe the reading in the voltmeter. Repeat the experiment for other values of current, in regular intervals. Tabulate these values and plot them. You are done.

Comment: Ok great I understand all that now. Just one final question, would it make a difference if the variable resistor was before the diode rather than after?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The purpose of the resistor is to control the amount of current flowing through the circuit. Whereever you connect, it is series with the diode and the battery and so there is no problem.